# How to setup OpenCV 2.0 with Microsoft VC++ 2010 express

Tags: opencv

Could someone please provide a step by step tutorial on how to setup openCV 2 with VC++2010 express? Im having major trouble doing the same..

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but having worked with OpenCV for almost a year now I would highly recommend the EmguCV wrapper instead of using OpenCV directly.  Your life will be much easier because you can use C# instead of C, C++, and Python.

Comment: EmguCV works with VC++ too? And are the functions etx the same or do i have to learn more?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918) that shows how to configure **OpenCV 2.3** on VS 2010. If you pay attention to the file names you will notice that they include the version of OpenCV, so just replace those for the appropriate version you are interested in installing.