# Setup OpenCV-2.3 for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv 2.3 with Visual Studio 2010 Express. My code is from example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <highgui.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int c;
    // allocate memory for an image
    IplImage *img;
    // capture from video device #1
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
    // create a window to display the images
    cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    // position the window
    cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 5, 5);
    while(1)
    {
        // retrieve the captured frame
        img=cvQueryFrame(capture);
        // show the image in the window
        cvShowImage("mainWin", img );
        // wait 10 ms for a key to be pressed
        c=cvWaitKey(10);
        // escape key terminates program
        if(c == 27)         
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What have I done so far?

- Added `build\bin` and one of `build\{x86|x64}\{vc9\vc10\mingw}\bin` to my system path (to use DLLs).
- Added `build\{x86|x64}\{vc9\vc10\mingw}\lib` or `build\{x86|x64}\{vc9\vc10\mingw}\staticlib` as library directories to my linker settings.
- Added `build\include` and `build\include\opencv` as include directories to my compiler settings.

And the result is:

> **1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'c:\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\vc10\lib.obj'**

There's no `lib.obj` in OpenCV folders. I've only unziped `OpenCV-2.3.0-win-superpack.exe`, without using CMake software.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Well, the [**official guide**](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++_VS2010) is for installing **OpenCV 2.1** on VS2010, so I wrote some instructions below that shows how to properly install and configure the **x86** version of **OpenCV 2.3** on **Visual Studio 2010** (Express), since a lot of folks seem to have problems setting it up correctly.

Download [*OpenCV-2.3.0-win-superpack.exe*](http://tenet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-win/2.3/OpenCV-2.3.0-win-superpack.exe) and execute it to extract all files to a folder named `OpenCV2.3`. Inside this folder there are 2 directories: `build` and `opencv`. All the setup on VS2010 will refer to the `build` directory. For practical purposes I moved the folder `OpenCV2.3` to my `C:\` drive, so pay attention to the paths I suggest on this guide as yours might be different.

On Visual Studio, create a new **Win32 Console Application** project and name it whatever you like. After that, a new window will show up. Click on the tab **Application Settings** and make sure the option **Empty Project** gets selected:

[image]

Add a new file `main.cpp` to the folder `Source Files`, then add this code to `main.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if (argc < 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./opencv_hello <file.png>\n");
    return -1;
}

    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
if (!img)
{
    return -1;
}

cvNamedWindow("display", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("display", img );

    cvWaitKey(0);        

    return 0;
}
```

At this point, we need to configure the project so it can locate OpenCV headers and libraries. Go to the Project Properties (**ALT+F7**), and once the new window shows up do the following:

- On the **Configuration** box, select **All Configurations**
- Open **Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General**, and edit the field **Additional Include Directories** to add these 3 paths (for the headers):

  `C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv`

  `C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv2`

  `C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include`

[image]

Note that `include\opencv` is for the C interface of OpenCV and `include\opencv2` if for the C++ interface. We are also adding the folder `include` to prevent our build from being broken by some headers of the C interface that refer to C++ headers as `opencv2\core`.

- Then, add the path of the libraries on **Configuration Properties > Linker > General**, and on the **Additional Library Directories** field, add this: `C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\vc9\lib`:

[image]

- Finally, for this simple test we are going to add the libraries `opencv_core230.lib` and `opencv_highgui230.lib`. So go to **Configuration Properties > Linker > Input** and add them:

[image]

When writing more complex applications you'll probably need to add other OpenCV libs that I did not 
mentioned on this little project of ours.

Press **F7** to *Build Solution* and you should see:

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

To be able to execute the application you'll need to [modify the **PATH** environment variable](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx) of your system to add the location of OpenCV's DLLs. Add this to end of PATH:

```
; C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\vc9\bin
```

Comment: @Elfoc Drastically improved answer to show steb-by-step how to configure OpenCV 2.3 and VS2010.

Comment: I have added e:\opencv\build\x86\vc9\bin  to system PATH envirenment variable. I am getting run time error: opencv_core231d.dll was not found  .... I am using Visual studio 2008, Pentium 4 m/c. Any idea what's the mistake?

Comment: did you restart your system after editing PATH var. A reboot is required so that VS see the change.

Comment: @karlphillip: Hi, 2.4.1 is released. Can you update your answer for that? Or is the procedure same. I tried as per this post:http://stackoverflow.com/q/10901905/1134940, but didn't work. Shows "opencv_core240d.dll is missing from the computer".

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I haven't installed 2.4.1 on Windows yet, I'll try it tonight and  then I'll let you know if I succeeded.

Comment: @karlphillip: it shows `cannot open file 'opencv_contrib240d.lib'`. What to do?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK The `d` at the end of the name indicates the debug version of the library. Maybe v2.4 don't include the debug version anymore and just the release. So try the name `opencv_contrib240.lib` instead.

Comment: No. it was because i used 2.4.1. so it is 241 instead of 240. Now it is compiled, but shows another problem "Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff)."

Comment: @AbidRahmanK That is a runtime error, something in the code failed. If you are using the code above, you'll see that it returns **-1** when it can't load the image.

Comment: @karlphillip: great my friend. Finally it worked for me. already +1-ed this answer. so +1 for your other link.

Answer (score 3):

If you are struggling with editing the PATH environment variables, you can also copy the required .dll files to your project folder:
**The dll files are located in this folder ../OpenCV2.3/build.x86/vc9/bin**

Then copy them to the folder where .exe file is created:
**c:\Users\PIMMES\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\eigenfaces\Debug** (Ofcourse you have to change the path to your Debug folder)

You only have to copy the .dll files which you are using in your project (#include  for example) For example if you get an error message saying opencv_core231d.dll is not found then get this .dll file from the above location (bin folder) and copy to your project Debug folder.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this alternate method. It worked flawlessly. I edited the Environment Path Variables correctly even though it was unable to detect the dll's correctly. Can you suggest me any possible reasons ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I make a program that uses opencv 2.2 or greater I include everything, and then comment out the libraries I don't need. Try this, I'm sure you need more than highgui.h

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_calib3d231.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_contrib231.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_core231.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_features2d231.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_flann231.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_gpu231.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_haartraining_engine.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_highgui231.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_imgproc231.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_legacy231.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_ml231.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_objdetect231.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_ts231.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/opencv_video231.lib")
```