# I can't run openCV2.3.1 with VS2010 because opencv_core231d.dll was not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

I installed openCV2.3.1 with VS2010. In VC++ Directories I set **Library Directories** to `C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib`. My code has no error but when I try to build it VC++2010 displays this error

> This application has failed strat because opencv_core231d.dll was not
>   found. Reinstall the application may fix this problem.

How do I setup openCV2.3.1 with VC++2010 to find the .dll?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [Microsoft Visual Studio tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) from the latest OpenCV documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the openCV2.3.1 yourself. We use cmake build tool in our project. And you should copy the `opencv_core231d.dll` to your `exe` directory so that your executable file can find the dll.
[Here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) is the Complete Installation guide for OpenCV.

Comment: I don't think one MUST build from source.  It's ok to go with the pre-built binaries, unless no fine-tuning is required. But the issue, IMO, is that the .dlls of OpenCV are not found.  You sure can copy them, but you'll be better off by adding the .dlls directory to the system PATH. See [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariable)

Answer (score 0):

**Download** and **install** the 2.3.1 [**superpack**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3.1/) for Windows and configure Visual Studio according to [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918). Even though the instructions are for the 2.3 version, the procedure remains the same and you just need to take care to use the appropriate paths and file names of v2.3.1 when following the steps.

Alternatively you could try to follow [Andrey's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291844/i-cant-run-opencv2-3-1-with-vs2010-because-opencv-core231d-dll-was-not-found/7292143#7292143), but I haven't test it yet.