# I can't run openCV2.3.1 with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I can't run openCV with VS2010. I downloaded OpenCV-2.3.1-win-superpack and extract openCV2.3.1 in C:\opencv and use CMake buide project into C:\opencv\vs2010. Next, I set include **all module** and lib to **C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib** and set Additional Dependencies to

**opencv_core231d.lib opencv_highgui231d.lib opencv_imgproc231d.lib opencv_features2d231d.lib opencv_calib3d231d.lib**

After that I copy from C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin to folder Debug in my project.

I build this code no any error.

```
include "stdafx.h"

include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main(){
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("Desert.jpg");
    cv::namedWindow("My Image");
    cv::imshow("My Image", image);
    cv::waitKey(5000);

    return 1;
}
```

but when I run this code it show this error alert.

Unhandled exception at 0x0f6d49a6 in OpenCV_Helloworld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000018.

when I click breake it show

**No Source Available 
No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed.
Call stack location:
KernelBase.dll!75289617()**

In openCV tutorial use old version for openCV installation. So I find in google and install follow that. I'm not sure I miss take in this code or installation.

I create new Project and config like this [Setup OpenCV-2.3 for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918) and copy all dll to Debug folder in my Project. I build no error but when I run it show this error.

```
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\PKRU\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\opencv_hello\Debug\opencv_core231d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16385_none_ebf82fc36c758ad5\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_hello.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[5308] opencv_hello.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: Indeed. Review your other questions and accept some answers. Meanwhile, check this guide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918 to know how to configure OpenCV 2.3 on VS2010. You will have to pay attention and use the name convention of 2.3.1 instead.

Comment: accept some answers dude, so people stop ignoring you. i have the same opencv problem.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked if the imread worked?

```
if ( image.data == NULL ) {
   // failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Options>Debugging>Symbol and check 'Microsoft symbol server' as Symbol file(.pdb) locations'. This worked for me to get rid of 'Cannot find or open the PDB file' error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy `opencv_highgui231d.dll` to the build output directory as well? I can see that it loads `opencv_core` dll but not the `highgui` one.