# Need assistance resolving LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core231.obj' when building an opencv helloworld with vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I followed the guide at the link below in order to get a hello world source to compile but I keep getting a link error as shown in the title.  I don't understand why.  I did include the file "opencv_core231.lib" from the vc10 directory in the linker input section of my project properties (among other things directed in the guide).  Any ideas?

[Setup OpenCV-2.3 for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Can you upload your vcproj file?

Comment: well i feel a bit inadequate.  I can't figure out how to attache a file here.  Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You may have forgot the .lib in the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies section. For example you have to write "opencv_core241d.lib" instead of "opencv_core241d"

Answer (score 1):

In the 4-6 weeks I've been working with OpenCV 2.3 and Microsoft Visual Studio, I have copied all needed .dll files to my project folders. I believe that this is just how it is "done". I'm not saying you can't have some sort of link-sheet that you can import every time, but it has been working fine for me.

If you are interested, I used this guide for setup:

> http://www.anlak.com/using-opencv-2-3-1-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial/

This guy uses a property sheet to make projects, further along the path, easier to make. It's a decent walkthrough, with the exception that I could not find the **property manager**, which can be revealed through "View > Other Windows > Property Manager".

Hope this shed some light on your issue.