# Set compiler path for OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

I have been trying to run some sample c programs that uses the cv.h library, but what happened was that the compile complains the file could not be found. So I am guessing I need to some how set the compiler's path. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux, I use **pkg-config** to assist me on that task:

```
g++ program.cpp -o program `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: You know the compiler complains about .h files for opencv2 as well. How come I don't find opencv2 in the /user/include/.. path? Is it because I didn't install the full version?

Comment: There a couple of things that could be causing this: an install problem, or a bad source code. Either way, I suggest you check http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide_Linux or the guide for Ubuntu, http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide%20%3A%20Debian. And most importantly, please first use a source code that you know it works (like this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918) to test your environment, and after that you are free to go on and write your own programs.

Answer (score 0):

With gcc, you need to add `-I/path/to/the/folder/where/cv.h/is/`. You'll probably also need the `-L/path/to/the/folder/where/libopencv.so/is -lopencv`.

Comment: I discovered that the necessary includes are in /usr/include/opencv. Shouldn't the compiler search in the place already?

Comment: With `#include <opencv/cv.h>`, it'll probably find it. Else, if you use `#include <cv.h>`, you'll need to add `-I/usr/include/opencv`.