# load image with openCV Mat c++

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, loadimage

I want to load an image using Mat in openCV

My code is:

```
Mat I = imread("C:/images/apple.jpg", 0);
namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", I );
```

I am getting the following error in a message box:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x70270149 in matching.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation 
reading location 0xcccccccc.
```

Please note that I am including:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
```

Answer (score 15):

I've [talked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8271889/176769) about this [so many times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14506326/176769) before, I guess it's pointless to do it again, but **code defensively**: if a method/function call can fail, make sure you know when it happens:

```
Mat I = imread("C:\\images\\apple.jpg", 0);
if (I.empty())
{
    std::cout << "!!! Failed imread(): image not found" << std::endl;
    // don't let the execution continue, else imshow() will crash.
}

namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", I ); 
waitKey(0);
```

Note that Windows' path uses backslash `\` instead of the standard `/` used on *nix systems. You need to escape the backslash when passing the filename: `C:\\images\\apple.jpg`

[Calling `waitKey()` is mandatory if you use `imshow()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16090881/176769)

**EDIT**:

If it's `cv::imread()` that is throwing the exception **the only solution I know to work is downloading OpenCV sources and building it** on the machine, since re-installing OpenCV doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @ karlphillip - even with your answer I am having the same problem.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x70270149 in matching.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.(displayed in a message box)

Comment: If it's `cv::imread()` I've seen this kind of exception being thrown before. The only solution was to download OpenCV sources and COMPILE it on the machine. Re-installing OpenCV didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @karlphillip If we want to read many images from different folder than what should we do for that ?

Comment: @Wish_2_fly If we want to store several different numbers, how do we do that in a program? `int n1 = 10; int n2 = 20; int n3 = 30; ...`

Comment: @karlphillip i know in a loop , `for(int n1=0;n1<=10;n1++)` but when i did it in my program , like ; `Mat T=imread("C:\Pick")` and than loop it , it didn't work , here is my question <a>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971530/how-to-get-the-area-of-the-image-and-equalize-all-the-images

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that I exists after imread? Perhaps the file read failed

After reading a file do `if ( I.empty() )` to check if it failed

Comment: @ Martin Beckett yes, there is image "apple.jpg"in the link C:/images/apple.jpg

Comment: Yes but what does "I.empty()" return? You might not have permission, the file migth be corrupt, you might not have the jpeg.dll etc etcv

Comment: @ Martin Beckett I am getting the above mentioned error- May be I do not have the library or I am wrongly performing the includes. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you don't have include problem because normally it .hpp file so you're suppose to do

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\eigen.hpp>
```

But your code seems good but add a `cv::waitKey(0);` after your imshow.

Comment: As @Martin Beckett said, can be just because C:/Images/apple didn't exist so your Mat is empty. So do if(!I.empty()).

Comment: @ Alexandre Bizeau when I copy and paste your include I am getting this error "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp'"

Comment: Does not necessarily copy exactly what I put because your Include Directories is maybe not set as mine. As I can see with your. You maybe just need to do #include <highgui.hpp> or maybe #include <highgui/highgui.hpp>. Depend how you set the folder and your project properties

Answer (score 0):

Are you using visual studio 2010 to run the OpenCV code? If so, try compiling in Release mode.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @karlphillip, however trivial it may sound but this statement " You need to escape the backslash when passing the filename: C:\images\apple.jpg" is really important.