# Opencv c++Template/Pattern Matching Scale and Rotation invariant

Tags: c++, opencv, scaling, template-matching

I want to see if a template in present in an image using openCv and c++.  However due to different distance  at which the image is taken and different position of the image, the match does not occur correctly.

here is my code:

```
IplImage* image    = cvLoadImage("C:/images/Photo0734.jpg", 1);
IplImage* templat  = cvLoadImage("C:/images/templatecoin.jpg", 1);
int percent =25;// declare a destination IplImage object with correct size, 
depth and  channels
IplImage* image3 = cvCreateImage( cvSize((int)((image->width*percent)/100) , 
(int)((image->height*percent)/100) ),image->depth, image->nChannels );

//use cvResize to resize source to a destination image
cvResize(image, image3);
IplImage* image2   = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image3->width, image3->height), 
IPL_DEPTH_8U,   1);
IplImage* templat2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(templat->width, 
templat->height),   IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 

cvCvtColor(image3, image2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvCvtColor(templat, templat2, CV_BGR2GRAY);


int w = image3->width - templat->width + 1;
int h = image3->height - templat->height + 1;
result = cvCreateImage(cvSize(w, h), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
cvMatchTemplate(image2, templat2, result, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);

double min_val, max_val;
CvPoint min_loc, max_loc;
cvMinMaxLoc(result, &min_val, &max_val, &min_loc, &max_loc);

cvRectangle(image3, max_loc, cvPoint(max_loc.x+templat->width, 
max_loc.y+templat->height), cvScalar(0,1,1), 1);

cvShowImage("src", image3);
//cvShowImage("result image", result);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

Please note that I am Unable to use "Mat". Is it possible to use IplImage* and enable the code to be invariant to scaling and rotation? help me.

Comment: Maybe "pattern" is a more suitable term than "template" for your question...

Answer (score 0):

Let have a look to that :

[SIFT Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform)

[SIFT example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461148/sift-implementation-with-opencv-2-2)

[OpenCV SIFT documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html)

I think that can be usefull for you.

Comment: @ Alexandre Bizeau- Hi, your example is using cv::Mat and i am not able to use it.  That is why I am asking if invariant rotation and scaling can be implemented with IplImage.

Comment: You cannot using because you are doing C ? Or I missing something ? Let me have a look for IplImage, if there a way to do it and to your code what the problem.

Comment: plz have a look to this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109471/load-image-with-opencv-mat-c  -I am unable to load an image with cv::Mat, however I manage to do so with IplImage

Comment: Instead of talking about cv::Mat (Mat you are talking about) can you use cvMat ? The C format for Mat ?

Comment: Okay, But once you have load an image with cvLoadImage can you convert it in cvMat, normally you should. You have a problem with your OpenCV configuration for sure if you cannot use Mat. Don't avoid your first problem. Try to solve that before because IplImage are not support for OpenCV now.

Comment: I will be very pleased if you could kindly explain to me how to convert cvLoadImage to cvMat.

Comment: Once you have done this : IplImage* image    = cvLoadImage("C:/images/Photo0734.jpg", 1); Try do to cvMat* myMat(image);  or cv::Mat* myMat(image); If I remember well.