# How to get the area of the image and equalize all the images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to get the area of the image like if the image is `150*30 pixels` , than it return/inform me this value`150*30` , and if i have multiple images and i want all of them to be of equal size like all of them to be the size of `150*30 pixels` than what should i do as i want to do this for train my data using `SVM`

Comment: i think area of image wouldn't be hardcoded,

Answer (score 0):

You should use the resize function, like this for example

```
resize(input,output,Size(150,30));
```

Comment: How to access many images for folder ? and resize them in a loop

Comment: I suggest you take a look at directory_iterator (Boost library) to go through a folder