# Load raw image data in Mat object in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, rawimage

I have the following problem. I'd try to load a raw image data in an opencv Mat object in order to apply post-processing image manipulation. My raw image is a 16 bit 3 channels image.
Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/58106/unable-to-open-raw-image-through-opencv/)?

Comment: I'll do it. Thanks

Comment: `cv::Mat img = cv::imread("path_to_img", cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH );`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [load image with openCV Mat c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109471/load-image-with-opencv-mat-c)