# Configure Openni with Opencv in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, openni

Im trying tu use OpenNi with OpenCV in VS2010. im not using Cmake. If some knows how to do it please help me.

Comment: [OpenCV 2.3 C++ Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918)