# How to begin a project on image enhancement using openCV?

Tags: opencv

Can anyone pls tell me how to start a project from the scratch using openCV.
my project is an image enhancing application software for windows

Comment: Question is not specific. Add details about what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Here is an idea: [configure your environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918) to compile OpenCV code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with OpenCV, first setup [OpenCV in windows](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html).

Read the book on OpenCV by Gary Bradsky , ["Learning OpenCV"](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=learning%20opencv%20book&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CFUQFjAG&url=http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0596516134&ei=lPQbT_fjKYuGrAf0vfDnDQ&usg=AFQjCNGNIqIFI3b2g6EkAgNpHswWc6idjA).

[Learn to build applications.](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html)

OpenCV hosts a list of [good tutorials.](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html)Check them out. And you can get a lot of tutorials by googling.