# Installing OpenCV HighGUI missing

Tags: windows, opencv, installation

I have some trouble installing OpenCV. I took the 2.3.1 windows superpack available here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/. I extracted it to C:\OpenCV and built it with CMake into the "OpenCV/build" directory, for Visual C++ 64 bits. 
An INSTALL file was generated, I built it in Debug and Release mode (64bits). Then I tried to do the same for the "minarea" sample file in "OpenCV/samples/c/example_cmake": generate the files with CMake and then build with Visual C++.

Throughout the entire process I had no decisive error I was aware of. But when I try to open the sample exe file, I get: "The program can't start because opencv_highgui231d.dll is missing". And hig

Comment: Problem solved.
For future records, the problem is solved by adding the folder where "opencv_core*d.dll" and "opencv_core*.dll" (where * is the version number), to your system path (see the "compile using visual studio" paragraph here :http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide).

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918) has step by step instructions on how to install OpenCV 2.3.x on Windows and configure VS2010 successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved. For future records, the problem is solved by adding the folder where "opencv_core*d.dll" and "opencv_core*.dll" (where * is the version number), to your system path (see the "compile using visual studio" paragraph here :[opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide))

Comment: Make sure its the dll's and not the lib's. Feeling very stupid. Copying these into the debug folder of the built app also seemed to work.