# Error Compiling a basic openCV program

Tags: c++, opencv, pkg-config

I installed openCV following the link mentioned below :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV#aStep_1

The installation went smooth, Now when I compile my test program:
using the following command :

```
opencv openCVtest.cpp
```

it throws me the following error :

```
compiling openCVtest.cpp
g++: error: missing argument to ‘-l’
Output file => openCVtest
```

I looked up the script I am using to compile ( its given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV#aStep_1) )
and saw this particular line that will be used to compile my c++ code :

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $1 .cpp` $1 `pkg-config --libs opencv`;
```

I understand that "-l" is asking for some libraries, but I think I  should not be passing anything other than my code to this script.

PS here is the detail of what's executed in that line:

```
hduser@ishan-Notebook-PC:~/Documents/OpenCv$ echo g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencvtest.cpp .cpp` opencvtest.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`

g++ -ggdb -I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv2 -o opencvtest opencvtest.cpp -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -l
```

Can you guys please help me figure out , what exactly am I doing wrong?
Thanks !

**UPDATE**

I found my opencv.pc file containing an extra "-l" I removed that flag and the above errors goes away :

contents of opencv.pc file:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: opencv
Description: The opencv library
Version: 2.x.x
Cflags: -I${includedir}/opencv -I${includedir}/opencv2
Libs: -L${libdir} -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -l
```

Notice the extra **"-l"** in last line.

However , now I get the following error :

```
openCVtest.cpp:1:39: fatal error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `pkg-config` is returning one extra `-l` at the end.
You can try running the command without it by hand:

```
g++ -ggdb -I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv2 -o opencvtest opencvtest.cpp -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy
```

**Update:**
For the second issue you are having, try to use the include paths without the `opencv` and `opencv2` directories.

So instead of this:

```
Cflags: -I${includedir}/opencv -I${includedir}/opencv2
```

Try this:

```
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Comment: hey @Lawrence , it took care of the above error but now it throws a new one :



openCVtest.cpp:1:39: fatal error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

I looked up /usr/include/opencv2 
the folder highgui isn't there at all ?? is this normal ? 
Should I be missing the basic header files after installation..

Comment: Could this be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509702/installing-opencv-highgui-missing

Comment: Hey @Lawrence, 
The guy in that post has windows , I think I need to look further ..