# Setup OpenCV in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have created a new project (without code) that uses OpenCV.
I the project properties I set the requirements like below:

library directory:

- C:\OpenCV-2.2.0\lib\Debug

include directories:

- C:\OpenCV-2.2.0\include\opencv
- C:\OpenCV-2.2.0\include\opencv2
- C:\OpenCV-2.2.0\include

The first lines of code :

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core230d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui230d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_video230d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_ml230d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_legacy230d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc230d.lib")
```

---

When I built my project I got no error but when I include the `<cv.h>` file, unresolved external errors appear.

To solve my problem any guide may help me.

Comment: What are the "unresolved external errors"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.3 C++ Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Search for my answer in the link above. It provides detailed instructions on how to configure OpenCV with VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven added the src directory files. Look at this page: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010

You need to add these folders:
Source Directories... add: 'C:\OpenCV2.1\src\cv; C:\OpenCV2.1\src\cvaux; C:\OpenCV2.1\src\cxcore; C:\OpenCV2.1\src\highgui; C:\OpenCV2.1\src\ml;'