# OnlineFaceRec by Shervin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to implement the online face recognition by Shervin which is available in his website: http://www.shervinemami.co.cc/faceRecognition.html

I downloaded the zip file and tried to run it but i am not able to do it. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

I am having this errors.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvEigenDecomposite referenced in function "void __cdecl learn(char *)" (?learn@@YAXPAD@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvCalcEigenObjects referenced in function "void __cdecl doPCA(void)" (?doPCA@@YAXXZ)
```

Not sure what these errors are and how to solve it...

Comment: To [configure VS2010 and OpenCV read this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918). Regarding the includes of string and vector, they belong to the standard C++ library, and Visual Studio shouldn't complain about them. Have you tried to googling these problems already?

Comment: these are errors after configuring...

Comment: didn't include the "stdafx.h".. thats why... but still got other errors...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what OpenCV version you are using, but if we assume that you have v2.3.0 you need to link your project with the library: **opencv_legacy230.lib** , which is where those symbols are defined.

Comment: So you are probably looking for **opencv_legacy210.lib**.

Comment: i dun have that lib where can i download it from?

Comment: Search for opencv_legacy instead of the full name of the file. I think this library already exists in v2.1. If not, try adding opencv_imgproc210.lib instead. The fact is that those symbols are inside one of the lib files in your OpenCV directory. You just need to find which one is it. A simple trial-and-error can accomplish that.