# How to import opencv libraries into eclipse using windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, gcc, opencv, mingw

i'm trying to import that libraries into eclipse using [that tutorial](http://www.velocino.it/2011/03/come-installare-la-libreria-opencv-su-eclipse-per-windows/). But i retrieve that error:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project OpenCVExample****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
gcc -IC:\OpenCV2.1\include\ -O0 -Wall -o src\example.o ..\src\example.c
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 68  ms.
```

What can i do? i follow all the tutorial line by line, can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**The error message doesn't say what the error was**, it just says that there was a problem.

Looking at the tutorial I can say there is **one obvious error**: while the tutorial assumes you installed v2.1, it gives you the link to download and install v2.2 (OpenCV-2.2.0-win32-vs2010.exe).

So one thing you need to **pay attention** is: if the version you installed is different from the one used in that tutorial, you need to take this into consideration when adjusting:

- The environment variable **PATH**;
- The directory name in `C/C++ Build -> Setting -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Directories`;
- And the name of the libraries in `MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries`.

For instance, the library names for v2.1 are:

```
cv210
highgui210
cxcore210
cvaux210
cxts210
ml210
opencv_ffmpeg210
```

But if you are using v2.2, you need to use:

```
cv220
highgui220
cxcore220
cvaux220
cxts220
ml220
opencv_ffmpeg220
```

Capiche?

Now, if you continue to have problems you can consider installing Visual Studio 2010 Express, which you can use and download for free. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918) will show you how to configure it for OpenCV.