# Plethora of CMake errors about absolute and relative destinations when generating OpenCV 2.4.6 (and a bit)

Tags: opencv, cmake

Having downloaded the latest OpenCV source code from [github](http://github.com/Itseez/opencv) on the 26th of October 2013 I have run CMake (cmake-gui 2.8.12) to first 'Configue' and then 'Generate' the projects. Generating the build directory throws a bunch of errors, starting with `Error in generation process, project files may be invalid`:

[image: error screenshot]

The first group I think it is safe for me to ignore, they look like this:

> CMake Warning (dev) in
>   apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:
>   Policy CMP0022 is not set:
>   INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES defines the
>   link   interface.  Run "cmake
>   --help-policy CMP0022" for policy details.  Use the   cmake_policy
>   command to set the policy and suppress
>   this warning.
>
> Static library target
>   "opencv_haartraining_engine" has a
>   INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property. 
>   This should be preferred as the source
>   of the link interface for this
>   library.  Ignoring the property and
>   using   the link implementation as the
>   link interface instead. This warning
>   is for project developers.  Use
>   -Wno-dev to suppress it.

But the last list of errors has me more worried. What are these? Should I act on them? How should I fix them?

> CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules") given absolute DESTINATION "/lib" but the export references an installation of target "opencv_core" which has relative DESTINATION "lib".
>
> CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules") given absolute DESTINATION "/lib" but the export references an installation of target "opencv_core" which has relative DESTINATION "bin".
>
> CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules") given absolute DESTINATION "/lib" but the export references an installation of target "opencv_flann" which has relative DESTINATION "lib".
>
> CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules") given absolute DESTINATION "/lib" but the export references an installation of target "opencv_flann" which has relative DESTINATION "bin".
>
> [...]
>
> CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules") given absolute DESTINATION "/lib" but the export references an installation of target "opencv_videostab" which has relative DESTINATION "lib".
>
> CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules") given absolute DESTINATION "/lib" but the export references an installation of target "opencv_videostab" which has relative DESTINATION "bin".

[image: cmake-gui screenshot of errors]

========== EDIT ===========

I wonder if the problem here is that the CMake value `CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS` which is present when running CMake on the code for release 2.4.6 is not present when running CMake on the latest code. If so, what is the fix?

Comment: I think this may be a bug so I have submitted it as [an OpenCV issue](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3350).

Comment: I have the same probleme .How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the same situation width you, cmake 2.8.12, OpenCV 2.4.6, what i chose for the "specify the generator for this project" was VS10(I used VC10), and chose "used default native compilers" under it. but I was success at last.

Comment: That's interesting jacpy, I'll try that. (N.B. I'll up-vote your answer too; it's annoying when people down-vote and don't bother explaining why, especially on your first SO answer.)