# Where are the correct include directories for OpenCV projects using a local build / selfbuild of OpenCV?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to debug [a frustrating problem whereby I cannot load video files in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19598664/575530). [One suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14820692/575530) is to abandon [the OpenCV pre-built libraries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/) and instead build OpenCV on the same machine as the failing project.

That is what I am now trying to do.

In the [OpenCV Quick Start about how to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to) one important step is to add the additional include directories to the project property sheet by opening the project's property pages, navigating to `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`. Using the pre-built distribution I am advised to add the directory `C:\OpenCV2.4.6\build\include` and indeed inside that directory are sub-directories `opencv` and `opencv2`. One of the files my project (like most OpenCV projects) will need is `highgui.hpp` from the line

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

In the pre-built OpenCV distribution `highgui.hpp` ends up in `C:\OpenCV2.4.6\build\include\opencv2\highgui` and is thus correctly picked up at compile time because of the additional include directory.

Having generated with CMake and built with Visual Studio 2012 the latest version of OpenCV on my machine (though [perhaps unsuccessfully](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19616558/575530)) I cannot find `highgui.hpp`. It is not in `C:\Users\timregan\Documents\GitHub\opencv\build\include` (in fact there are no sub-directories `opencv` nor `opencv2` in there). It is in C:\opencv-2.4\modules\highgui\include\opencv2\highgui.

What step, flag, etc. did I omit in order to generate place it correctly on my machine? Why are the `opencv` and `opencv2` sub-directories missing completely from `C:\Users\timregan\Documents\GitHub\opencv\build\include` after I have generated and built OpenCV?

(N.B. I'm using CMake 2.8.12 and Visual Studio 2012 on a Windows 8 machine.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open the visual studio solution and right click on install project and then build. the include files should appear in `C:\Users\timregan\Documents\GitHub\opencv\selfbuild\install`