# Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv

I am trying to run the squares.cpp example in the openCV 2.2. The code compiles and builds without errors in Visual Studio 2008. However when I run the executable (i.e., during run time) I am getting a error stating

`Unhandled exception at 0x004ac363 in OpenCVRectangle.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.`

This occurs at the definition:
    `vector<vector<Point> > squares;` 
in the main function

Can somebody help, why this occurs? 
I figured out that the value 0xcccccc usually is an uninitialized or bad variable, but do not understand why I get this exception at this line.

The full example code can be found at http://pastebin.com/MTaXVcQz

Comment: 0xCCCCCCCC is uninitialized memory [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine on Mac OS X with OpenCV 2.3.0, but OpenCV is known to present different behaviors in different Operating Systems.

- First, check if your code has this problem in both Release and Debug versions.
- Upgrade to OpenCV [2.3.1 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918) and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

`namedWindow` in the code you linked to is a function which doesn't look defined in this scope.  It might be that it's trying to interpret as a variable which has not been defined, rather than a function.  I would say it's missing some sort of library perhaps?  It's difficult to say without further context, but `vector<vector<Point> > squares;` should *not* be a violation.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl + Alt + E in VS, enable all exceptions checking, run it in debug mode and see the place where the exception is rised. This should be enough for understanding.