# Opencv2.1 application build in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have an openCv application that builds and runs fine when using the Mutithreaded Debug Dll option for code generation property. However, I would like to run the application on any computer however, the build fails in Multithreaded Debug mode giving LNK 2005 errors, some examples are

> 1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall
>   std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined
>   in libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)
>
> 1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall
>   std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined
>   in libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj)
>
> 1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl
>   std::_Debug_message(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)"
>   (?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z) already defined in
>   libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj)
>
> 1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall
>   std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)"
>   (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in opencv2.obj
>
> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall
>   std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)"
>   (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in
>   LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
>
> 1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void
>   __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in
>   opencv2.obj
>
> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter
>   already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
>
> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already
>   defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrptw.obj)
>
> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall
>   std::exception::exception(char const * const &)"
>   (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) already defined in
>   LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
>
> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual
>   __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in
>   LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
>
> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fclose already defined
>   in LIBCMTD.lib(fclose.obj)
>
> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fprintf already defined
>   in LIBCMTD.lib(fprintf.obj)
>
> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fopen already defined
>   in LIBCMTD.lib(fopen.obj)
>
> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _memmove already defined
>   in LIBCMTD.lib(memmove.obj)
>
> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in
>   LIBCMTD.lib(dbgfree.obj)

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I am really stuck here, there is no problem with smaller programs

Thanks

P.S I also use functions from cvBlobslib and code from LIBSVM but it should not be the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.3 C++ Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

If you change to use `/MT` and `/MTd`, then all your dependent libraries also need to have been compiled with these settings.

If this is not the case, then these dependencies require linking to the dynamic CRT and your project is trying to link to the static CRT, causing the "already defined" errors you're seeing.