# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/opencv.h': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv, gpu

Though I have well configured the opencv 2.3 with gpu support on visual studio 2008 still I m getting the above error.

Can anybody please suggest me where I am doing wrong.

I am just trying to create  simple application

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.3 C++ Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: If you had it well configured, that error wouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include it via

```
#include <...>
```

or

```
#include "..."
```

Try to use the latter one and insert the full path to the opencv.h file to check you installation. In case you want to use the above way, you need to introduce the path where you installed opencv to your compiler... See Vistual Studio Project properties for details.

Best regards, foxtrott

Comment: I used the later one with full path still it is giving me error

Comment: Try this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/03971022-d67a-42b6-8388-397babd9c0fc