# Issue in integrating OpenCV 2.0 with Visual c++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, opencv

i have followed [the steps](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++_VS2008) to install OpenCV with visual studio 2008, then i made a windows form application, like File->new->project->Visual C++->CLR->Windows Forms Application,i named it "ImageProcessing" after that i include these files in the file ImageProcessing.cpp:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

next, i dragged a button inside the ready made form and inside it's action i typed this statement:

```
IplImage *loadedImage=cvLoadImage("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Owner\\Desktop\\aya.jpg");
```

but when i tried to build the project these errors arises to me:

```
error C2065: 'IplImage' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'loadedImage' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'cvLoadImage': identifier not found
```

i'm sure that the OpenCV installation steps is correct as i tried the same steps with another project but it was with different template, it was like that File->new->project->Visual C++->Win32->Win32 project, i'm not sure if there's a difference with these two templates which causes the above errors to occur, if any one is able to resolve that,please let me know,thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.3 C++ Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Follow the steps of the post I just shared, but be careful to replace the names of the files for the ones that represent OpenCV 2.0

Comment: thanks Karlphillip, i have resolved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The main reason of these errors was that:**

1. i have included `#include "stdafx.h"` as the last header which
   is wrong as the compiler ignores any headers before `"stdafx.h"` , so
   i put it in the lead.

Comment: It would have been impossible for us to point this error since you only shared partial source code, and the actual problem was left out of your question. May this be a lesson for your future questions.