# Compiling opencv simple program results in conflict with windows sdk

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

This is my first experience with opencv. I downloaded it and set the visual studio 2010 (pro) include directories like this:

```
C:\opencv\build\include\opencv
C:\opencv\build\include
```

The "inherited" values are:

```
$(VCInstallDir)include
$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include
$(WindowsSdkDir)include
$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include
```

But when I compile I get errors regarding the windows sdk...

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(212): error C2011: 'sockaddr' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(485) : see declaration of 'sockaddr'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(390): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(443): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(443): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(443): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(524): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSA' : macro redefinition
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(287) : see previous definition of 'IN_CLASSA'
...
```

There is some conflict with the sdk include files. Does anyone know how can I fix this?
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.3 C++ Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: It is not. I read that thread, it is completely unrelated...

Comment: If you don't include OpenCV headers/code, will this error occur?

Comment: I see at least 1 suspicious include: either `$(WindowsSdkDir)include` or `$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include`, or are they different SDKs ?

Comment: they are different sdks. But only get problems with the $(WindowsSdkDir) one. All other projects compile fine. Only have problems with the opencv ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was using winsock2.h and it conflicts for some reason with opencv. changed it to winsock.h

Comment: Is it something like opencv and winsock cannot work together?