# OpenCV installation VS 10 won't build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I keep on trying to install OpenCV but there is always an Issue. The lastest thing I tried is this :

[Setup OpenCV-2.3 for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918)

but after runing the core I get this error.

> 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Napster\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\open23\Debug\open23.exe', Symbols loaded. 'open23.exe':
>   Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source
>   information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Users\Napster\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\open23\Debug\opencv_highgui230.dll', Cannot find or open
>   the PDB file 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols
>   loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source
>   information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Users\Napster\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\open23\Debug\opencv_core230.dll', Cannot find or open
>   the PDB file 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_none_50940634bcb759cb\msvcp90.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_none_50940634bcb759cb\msvcr90.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16385_none_ebf82fc36c758ad5\comctl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avifil32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvfw32.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avicap32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded. 'open23.exe':
>   Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source
>   information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Program Files\CheckPoint\ZAForceField\WOW64\Plugins\ISWSHEX.dll',
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\msvcr80.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\msvcp80.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped). 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Program Files\CheckPoint\ZAForceField\WOW64\AK\icsak.dll', Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file First-chance exception at 0x7605b727
>   (KernelBase.dll) in open23.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:
>   std::exception at memory location 0x0015f4d0.. 'open23.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). First-chance exception at 0x7605b727 (KernelBase.dll) in
>   open23.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::exception at memory location
>   0x0015f858.. The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xd20) has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). The program '[2392] open23.exe: Native' has exited with code -1
>   (0xffffffff).

my Code

> ## include
>
> ## include
>
> ## include
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { if (argc < 2) {
>       printf("Usage: ./opencv_hello \n");
>       return -1; }
>
> ```
> IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); if (!img) {
> return -1; }
> ```
>
> cvNamedWindow("display", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
>       cvShowImage("display", img );
>
> ```
> cvWaitKey(0);        
>
> return 0; }
> ```

Extra info: I copied the dll from opencv to the debug folder because before I had an error that some dll was not found.

Also, I'm a noob and this is my first major c++ personal project on the side. So it is the first time that I tried to use an extra library to create a program.

Thank you

Comment: A C++ exception is thrown and the program exits. How should anyone help you without seeing the code?

Comment: I used the same code as in the Link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use opencv with visual studio - start here [How to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to), it explains how to setup all the include and library paths correctly

Also you are mixing C++ headers and the old C function names - use the style in the example

Comment: Thanks!

I'm a bit of a noob,
I would like to create a facial recognition program but I have no idea where to go from here. Do you have some tips?

Thanks

Comment: Haar cascade, see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect.html

Answer (score 0):

Nm,

I used this code and it worked!

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h> 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "funny-pictures-cat-goes-pew.jpg" );
 cvNamedWindow( "MyJPG", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 cvShowImage("MyJPG", img);
 cvWaitKey(0);
 cvReleaseImage( &img );
 cvDestroyWindow( "MyJPG" );
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting the "Cannot find or open the PDB" warnings in future and googling this answer: this most likely means that you are including 32bit (x86) openCV libraries instead of 64bit (x64) ones