# OpenCV highgui220.dll missing

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++-2010

After installing Opencv2.2 using [this](http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/installing-and-using-opencv-with-visual-studio-2010-express/) tutorial I tried to run a simple sample script. It gave me the following error, however: **The program can't start because opencv_highgui220.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.** But I did, in fact, add the .dll to the Library Directories. I actually did everything the tutorial did too. I also tried to copy the .dll file to the general visual studio lib folder and then tried this `#pragma comment (lib, opencv_highgui220)` but I got the same error. Does anyone know how it is possible visual C++ still thinks the .dll does not exist? Thanks!

The option `use library dependence inputs` is set to `yes`.

Comment: seems like the dll had not been copied in your executable folder

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.3 C++ Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLL is missing from your system's environment and has nothing to do with compiling and linking your executable (i.e. adding the DLL folder to your Library directories folder is meaningless).

Add the DLL folder to your system path (System Variable PATH in Environment variables).

Comment: You need to add the full path (`"C:\Foo\OpenCV2.2\bin"`) to your System Path

Comment: I was changing the environment setting in visual studio itself whilst I should have been changing the environment variable in win7. It works now.