# Opencv in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenCV 2.3 C++ Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010)

I'm running a simple opencv program to display an image running visual studio. I have followed the process at willow garage. In the debug mode I'm getting error code (0xc0150002). Dependency walker says missing msvcp90d.dll, msvcr90d.dll, ieshims.dll. I have installed all libraries for visual studio and there's no such dll's on the system. However there are msvcp100.dll, msvcr100.dll.

But if I intead write a simple code to print '!', then the code works.

Please help.

Comment: Which version of OpenCV? Have you built it yourself?

Comment: the version is 2.1; I'm using the pre built libraries

Comment: Have you tried with any other version?