# Unable to remove Linker error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, opencv, linker

I am trying to use OpenCv in Visual Studio 2012. I followed every single step [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010) question has provided and every other that can be found on the internet. I even tried to work with different versions of opencv but the error didn't go away.

The error is:

`error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d230d.obj'`

All the required libraries are included in linker configurations of visual Studio. Envoirnmental variable "Path" has also been updated but still the error is there.

What can I do to solve this problem?
I have search for `calib3d230d.obj` every where but it is not inside the extracted folder.

I downloaded OpenCv `superpack.exe` from [HERE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3/)

Regards

Comment: Does the file exist? Or should it be generated?

Comment: I have search every where but I didn't find it in the folder in which I extracted OpenCv

Comment: Have you downloaded a binary distribution of OpenCV or did you build it yourself?

Comment: Maybe the path where the object file is to be generated is readonly.

Comment: How can I find where the object file is to generated

Comment: @junix I downloaded the binary.

Comment: come on any one help please

Comment: opencv_calib3d230d.lib exists in several locations for different architectures. I have not used OpenCV, but I looking at the old "tutorial" and downloading the superpack it looks as though they may be building for more architectures and compilers now. Instead of just specifying the `...\build` folder on the linker path list, try specifying the folders with computer architecture and visual studio compiler version such as `...\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\vc10\lib`. I believe vc10 is visual studio 2010 (vc9.0 was 2008 at least), but I am not positive on this count so you may still have issues linking.

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment a little more since I am no longer able to edit it. The file opencv_calib3d230d with the extension `.lib` exists (not `.obj`) but this file probably has the definitions the linker is seeking for static linking.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be linking to .lib files, opencv does not normally include any .obj files. Change this in your linker dependencies. Secondly, do you definitely have the debug version of the libraries? If not, then you need to specify the static libraries without the d on the end of the name (opencv_calib3d230d.lib -> opencv_calib3d230.lib).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem before. Finally I found that I forgot to type ".lib" after the library file in vc++ linker.

Wish this can help you.