# installing OpenCV-2.3.0-win-superpack on visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, 64-bit

I'm trying to installing OpenCV-2.3.0-win-superpack on visual studio 2010 and search in many site but I could not .my OS is x64 I'm really confounded that how to install it. any one know that please help me 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install the latest version available: [OpenCV 2.4.3 for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.3/OpenCV-2.4.3.exe/download), unless you have a very good reason to stick with the old 2.3.0.

Then check our [guide to configure Visual Studio and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7014918/176769). Note that the guide is for version 2.3.0, so if you upgrade to 2.4.3 you'll have to pay attention to the filenames and paths, because OpenCV appends the version to some filenames.