# Installing OpenCV in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, linker, installation

Im trying to install OpenCV to work with Visual Studio. I'm using the 2012Pro version but I think it should be the same as vs10. 
I was following this tutorial:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to

I have A Solution with only one Project And with only one file. For testing purposes I used the same code as in the tutorial.

```
// Video Image PSNR and SSIM
#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <iomanip>  // for controlling float print precision
#include <sstream>  // string to number conversion

#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // Gaussian Blur
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat, Scalar)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  // OpenCV window I/O

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

double getPSNR ( const Mat& I1, const Mat& I2);
Scalar getMSSIM( const Mat& I1, const Mat& I2);

static void help()
{
    cout
        << "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl
        << "This program shows how to read a video file with OpenCV. In addition, it tests the"
        << " similarity of two input videos first with PSNR, and for the frames below a PSNR "  << endl
        << "trigger value, also with MSSIM."<< endl
        << "Usage:"                                                                       << endl
        << "./video-source referenceVideo useCaseTestVideo PSNR_Trigger_Value Wait_Between_Frames " << endl
        << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------"   << endl
        << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    help();
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        cout << "Not enough parameters" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    stringstream conv;

    const string sourceReference = argv[1],sourceCompareWith = argv[2];
    int psnrTriggerValue, delay;
    conv << argv[3] << argv[4];       // put in the strings
    conv >> psnrTriggerValue >> delay;// take out the numbers

    char c;
    int frameNum = -1;          // Frame counter

    VideoCapture captRefrnc(sourceReference),
                 captUndTst(sourceCompareWith);

    if ( !captRefrnc.isOpened())
    {
        cout  << "Could not open reference " << sourceReference << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if( !captUndTst.isOpened())
    {
        cout  << "Could not open case test " << sourceCompareWith << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Size refS = Size((int) captRefrnc.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
                     (int) captRefrnc.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)),
         uTSi = Size((int) captUndTst.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
                     (int) captUndTst.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

    if (refS != uTSi)
    {
        cout << "Inputs have different size!!! Closing." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    const char* WIN_UT = "Under Test";
    const char* WIN_RF = "Reference";

    // Windows
            namedWindow(WIN_RF, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
            namedWindow(WIN_UT, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
            cvMoveWindow(WIN_RF, 400       ,            0);      //750,  2 (bernat =0)
            cvMoveWindow(WIN_UT, refS.width,            0);      //1500, 2

    cout << "Frame resolution: Width=" << refS.width << "  Height=" << refS.height
         << " of nr#: " << captRefrnc.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) << endl;

    cout << "PSNR trigger value " <<
          setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(3) << psnrTriggerValue << endl;

    Mat frameReference, frameUnderTest;
    double psnrV;
    Scalar mssimV;

    for(;;) //Show the image captured in the window and repeat
    {
        captRefrnc >> frameReference;
        captUndTst >> frameUnderTest;

        if( frameReference.empty()  || frameUnderTest.empty())
        {
            cout << " < < <  Game over!  > > > ";
            break;
        }

        ++frameNum;
        cout <<"Frame:" << frameNum;

        ///////////////////////////////// PSNR ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        psnrV = getPSNR(frameReference,frameUnderTest);                 //get PSNR
        cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(3) << psnrV << "dB";

        //////////////////////////////////// MSSIM /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (psnrV < psnrTriggerValue)
        {
            mssimV = getMSSIM(frameReference,frameUnderTest);

            cout << " MSSIM: "
                 << "R" << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(3) << mssimV.val[2] * 100
                 << "G" << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(3) << mssimV.val[1] * 100
                 << "B" << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(3) << mssimV.val[0] * 100;
        }

       cout << endl;

        ////////////////////////////////// Show Image /////////////////////////////////////////////
        imshow( WIN_RF, frameReference);
        imshow( WIN_UT, frameUnderTest);

        c = (char)cvWaitKey(delay);
        if (c == 27) break;
    }

    return 0;
}

double getPSNR(const Mat& I1, const Mat& I2)
{
    Mat s1;
    absdiff(I1, I2, s1);       // |I1 - I2|
    s1.convertTo(s1, CV_32F);  // cannot make a square on 8 bits
    s1 = s1.mul(s1);           // |I1 - I2|^2

    Scalar s = sum(s1);         // sum elements per channel

    double sse = s.val[0] + s.val[1] + s.val[2]; // sum channels

    if( sse <= 1e-10) // for small values return zero
        return 0;
    else
    {
        double  mse =sse /(double)(I1.channels() * I1.total());
        double psnr = 10.0*log10((255*255)/mse);
        return psnr;
    }
}

Scalar getMSSIM( const Mat& i1, const Mat& i2)
{
    const double C1 = 6.5025, C2 = 58.5225;
    /***************************** INITS **********************************/
    int d     = CV_32F;

    Mat I1, I2;
    i1.convertTo(I1, d);           // cannot calculate on one byte large values
    i2.convertTo(I2, d);

    Mat I2_2   = I2.mul(I2);        // I2^2
    Mat I1_2   = I1.mul(I1);        // I1^2
    Mat I1_I2  = I1.mul(I2);        // I1 * I2

    /*************************** END INITS **********************************/

    Mat mu1, mu2;   // PRELIMINARY COMPUTING
    GaussianBlur(I1, mu1, Size(11, 11), 1.5);
    GaussianBlur(I2, mu2, Size(11, 11), 1.5);

    Mat mu1_2   =   mu1.mul(mu1);
    Mat mu2_2   =   mu2.mul(mu2);
    Mat mu1_mu2 =   mu1.mul(mu2);

    Mat sigma1_2, sigma2_2, sigma12;

    GaussianBlur(I1_2, sigma1_2, Size(11, 11), 1.5);
    sigma1_2 -= mu1_2;

    GaussianBlur(I2_2, sigma2_2, Size(11, 11), 1.5);
    sigma2_2 -= mu2_2;

    GaussianBlur(I1_I2, sigma12, Size(11, 11), 1.5);
    sigma12 -= mu1_mu2;

    ///////////////////////////////// FORMULA ////////////////////////////////
    Mat t1, t2, t3;

    t1 = 2 * mu1_mu2 + C1;
    t2 = 2 * sigma12 + C2;
    t3 = t1.mul(t2);              // t3 = ((2*mu1_mu2 + C1).*(2*sigma12 + C2))

    t1 = mu1_2 + mu2_2 + C1;
    t2 = sigma1_2 + sigma2_2 + C2;
    t1 = t1.mul(t2);               // t1 =((mu1_2 + mu2_2 + C1).*(sigma1_2 + sigma2_2 + C2))

    Mat ssim_map;
    divide(t3, t1, ssim_map);      // ssim_map =  t3./t1;

    Scalar mssim = mean( ssim_map ); // mssim = average of ssim map
    return mssim;
}
```

I've downloaded the 2.4.3 version and I extracted it to C:\BUILD\
So Now I have C:\BUILD\opencv and so forth

In the property manager in visual studio I go to the Microsoft.Cpp.Win.32.user sheet and I change the following: (according to said tutorial and other solutions here in stack overvlow)

In *C/C++ -> General* I added in *Additional Include Directories*

```
C:\BUILD\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2\core
C:\BUILD\opencv\include\opencv
C:\BUILD\opencv\include\opencv2
C:\BUILD\opencv\build\include
C:\BUILD\opencv\build\include\opencv2
C:\BUILD\opencv\build\include\opencv
```

In *Linker->General* I added in *Additional Library Directories*

```
C:\BUILD\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib
```

In *Linker->Input->Additional dependencies*

```
opencv_core243.lib
opencv_imgproc243.lib
opencv_highgui243.lib
opencv_ml243.lib
opencv_video243.lib
opencv_features2d243.lib
opencv_calib3d243.lib
opencv_objdetect243.lib
opencv_contrib243.lib
opencv_legacy243.lib
opencv_flann243.lib
```

(yes I know about the d for the debug. But neither is working)

I Try to build the solution and I get the following error:

```
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0_InputArray@cv@@QAE@ABVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Mat & __cdecl cv::operator-=(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (??Zcv@@YAAAVMat@0@ABV10@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(class cv::Mat &)" (??0_OutputArray@cv@@QAE@AAVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Mat & __cdecl cv::operator-=(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (??Zcv@@YAAAVMat@0@ABV10@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::_OutputArray const & __cdecl cv::noArray(void)" (?noArray@cv@@YAABV_OutputArray@1@XZ) referenced in function "class cv::Mat & __cdecl cv::operator-=(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (??Zcv@@YAAAVMat@0@ABV10@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::convertTo(class cv::_OutputArray const &,int,double,double)const " (?convertTo@Mat@cv@@QBEXABV_OutputArray@2@HNN@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class cv::MatExpr __thiscall cv::Mat::mul(class cv::_InputArray const &,double)const " (?mul@Mat@cv@@QBE?AVMatExpr@2@ABV_InputArray@2@N@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::copySize(class cv::Mat const &)" (?copySize@Mat@cv@@QAEXABV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::Mat(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::subtract(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,int)" (?subtract@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@0ABV_OutputArray@1@0H@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Mat & __cdecl cv::operator-=(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (??Zcv@@YAAAVMat@0@ABV10@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::divide(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,double,int)" (?divide@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@0ABV_OutputArray@1@NH@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl cv::sum(class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?sum@cv@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@1@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function "double __cdecl getPSNR(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getPSNR@@YANABVMat@cv@@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl cv::mean(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?mean@cv@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@1@ABV_InputArray@1@0@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::absdiff(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &)" (?absdiff@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@0ABV_OutputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function "double __cdecl getPSNR(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getPSNR@@YANABVMat@cv@@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::Mat(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::MatExpr __cdecl cv::operator+(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (??Hcv@@YA?AVMatExpr@0@ABVMat@0@0@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::MatExpr __cdecl cv::operator+(class cv::MatExpr const &,class cv::Scalar_<double> const &)" (??Hcv@@YA?AVMatExpr@0@ABV10@ABV?$Scalar_@N@0@@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::MatExpr __cdecl cv::operator*(double,class cv::Mat const &)" (??Dcv@@YA?AVMatExpr@0@NABVMat@0@@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::GaussianBlur(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::Size_<int>,double,double,int)" (?GaussianBlur@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@V?$Size_@H@1@NNH@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Scalar_<double> __cdecl getMSSIM(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &)" (?getMSSIM@@YA?AV?$Scalar_@N@cv@@ABVMat@2@0@Z)
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvMoveWindow referenced in function _main
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvWaitKey referenced in function _main
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::namedWindow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?namedWindow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0VideoCapture@cv@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture(void)" (??1VideoCapture@cv@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::isOpened(void)const " (?isOpened@VideoCapture@cv@@UBE_NXZ) referenced in function _main
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual double __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::get(int)" (?get@VideoCapture@cv@@UAENH@Z) referenced in function _main
```

I tried to look at similar problems here but all solutions come to adding the actual libraries to the Addicionl Dependencies. Wich I have done. So I don't know...

Comment: You are missing some core opencv includes and/or libs.

Comment: In Linker->Input->Additional dependencies, are you sure that the name of the files match exactly the name of the files in "...\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.3 C++ Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the OpenCv path to your Environment Details? it is usually the first step that most of the tutorials tell you to do.

However if this does not work here is the [link](http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/) that I always use to help me set it up. It is using version of VS 2012 and OpenCV 2.4.3, so it is very similar to your problem.