# Error in using opencv

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

I have problem when debugging my program stated like that

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cv210d.lib'

I tried every thing stated in tutorials 
and all the solutions described in this website and other websites

I used **opencv 2.1.0** and **visual studio 2008**

I tried using **cv210.lib** in **debug** and **release**

I tried using **cv210d.lib** in **debug** and **cv210.lib** in **release**

I tried changing environmental variables

and other solutions but the same problem occures

I searched for **cv210.lib** in the **opencv** folder but it doesn't exist

I need it for my project 
so can you help me in solving this problem?

Comment: cv210D.lib is **not found** in the search directories.
If you want more specific help, please attach your directory settings, and the location of the file.

Comment: did you add cv210d.lib to your solution? (hint: solution options)

Comment: do you mean these directories V/c++ directories in include files C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv in library files C:\OpenCV2.1\lib in source files C:\OpenCV2.1\src\cv C:\OpenCV2.1\src\cvaux C:\OpenCV2.1\src\cxcore C:\OpenCV2.1\src\highgui C:\OpenCV2.1\src\ml for the additional dependencies debug configuration cv210d.lib cxcore210d.lib highgui210d.lib release configuration cv210.lib cxcore210.lib highgui210.lib –

Comment: Now can you make a search on where exactly cv210d.lib is located? (talking about debug mode here)

Comment: I searched the OpenCv2.1 folder for debug but i didn't find it .... and for the cv210d.lib and I didn't find it ... so do u mean searching in another folder ???

Comment: how to add it and from where ??

Comment: Get another distribution of opencv, preferably one that is linked statically. As your compiler says, it **needs** these files.

Comment: Make sure you have installed OpenCV successfully (hopefully a more recent version), then go through this [tutorial to configure your environment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7014918/176769).