# "opencv_highgui249.dll is missing" message on running c++ program on VS2013 Express Desktop

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918) but substituted for VS2013 express and OpenCV 2.4.9 whenever necessary. Shows no errors but gives a message that opencv_highgui249.dll is missing. What's wrong?

Comment: dll is missing, you should add your opencv bin path(where opencv dll exist) to your environment variable(windows PC).

Comment: I did that, but no avail. I then copied all the dll files into my project's debug folder and it worked. Problem is, I read somewhere that that isn't a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because the OpenCV DLLs are not found.

The locations that are searched for dependent dynamically linked libraries are rougly detailed within the LoadLibrary Windows API function documentation: (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx). I will not detail on this...

In the StackOverflow guide you were instructed to add the path to the 2.4.9 OpenCV Dlls to the PATH environment variable. Did you do so? If you did it might be that you have to restart Visual Studio (environment variables get read in only at process start).

Quote from original Stack Overflow guide

**"To be able to execute the application you'll need to [modify the PATH environment variable](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx) of your system to add the location of OpenCV's DLLs. Add this to end of PATH:
; C:\OpenCV2.3\build\x86\vc9\bin"**.

Of course another solution would be to simply copy the OpenCV DLLs to the folder where your exe gets written by the build. This is the first location that is searched for DLLs on startup.