# Visual Studio 2013 OpenCV Linker Error

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, linker, linker-errors

I am trying to compile an OpenCV example ([Setup OpenCV-2.3 for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918)) but I can't seem to get it to work. I followed the tutorial, and everything up to the running seems to work fine, but as soon as I try to run the example, the linker throws up errors. The weird thing is that when i `-verbose`, I get the following message:

```
1>  Unused libraries:
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_calib3d2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_contrib2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_core2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_features2d2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_flann2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_gpu2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_highgui2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_imgproc2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_legacy2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ml2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_nonfree2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_objdetect2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ocl2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_photo2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_stitching2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_superres2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ts2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_video2411d.lib
1>    D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_videostab2411d.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\user32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\gdi32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\winspool.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\comdlg32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\advapi32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\shell32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\ole32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\oleaut32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\uuid.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbc32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbccp32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib
1>  
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvNamedWindow referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvShowImage referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvLoadImage referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvWaitKey referenced in function _main
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\testOpenCV\Debug\testOpenCV.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The 'unused libraries' gives me all the OpenCV Libraries I included, but somehow the linker doesn't use the libraries, while they are necessary to be able to run the program. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Apparently you're trying to link with 64-bit libraries for a 32-bit compilation.

Comment: Thanks! That was the culprit...